# ADB connection to an AndroidTV

Tags: sony, google-tv

I've just got a Sony KDL-43W800C, and I intend to develop some apps for it, however I can not find any information on how to attach to it using adb for installing apks and getting the logs etc.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You need to use ADB over TCP/IP.

1. Enable Developer options: Press Home and select Settings. In the TV row, select About. Scroll down to and click on Build several times until a dialog appears with the message "You are now a developer" appears.
2. Enable Debugging: Press Home and go back into the Settings menu. In the System Preferences row, select Developer options, select Debugging, select ADB Debugging, select On.
3. Find the TV IP address: Press Home and select Network Settings.
4. Make sure your TV and your computer are connected to the same local network.
5. On your computer type: `adb connect <TV IP address>`
6. In the Allow debugging? dialog, select Always allow from this computer and select OK.

You can verify the connection is established and that the TV is communicating across the network with the following command:

```
adb logcat
```

Comment: Is there no way to enable ADB over USB? Using TCP/IP makes it difficult to debug the device if the network connection is dropped...

Comment: At this time ADB over USB is not available. If your Wi-Fi network is unstable just use wired Ethernet instead.

Comment: what is the port number that is used? 5555?

Comment: It's 5555. Also, I had to hard reboot (unplug power) between steps 1 and 2 to have the Developer options menu option show up.

Comment: @SiekermanTechnology Somehow the menu do not refresh by itself when you get the developer privilege. You just have to press back until you land on the home page and then get back to the menu.

Comment: 1) Find the TV IP address. 2) Command adb connect <ip tv>:5555. I use Sony. Lets go to work. :)

Comment: I still get connection denied with error code 10061 when we are on the same WiFi network (my laptop and my Android TV box). Could it be a hardware limitation ?

Comment: I had to close Android studio, before that the connection kept failing.

Comment: @TonniLarsenSONY is ADB over USB is still not supported in 2019?

Comment: To find the TV IP address: Go to Settings > About > Status > IP Address.

Comment: The option "ADB Debugging" is not visible. I only have USB  Debugging.
I have a skyworth android TV v8.0

Comment: @Burnsys Turning on USB Debugging seemed to activate "ADB over IP" for me and now port 5555 is open and adb can connect. I have Android TV 9.

Comment: The option "ADB Debugging" is not visible. I only have USB Debugging. I have a View Sonic Panel v8.0

Comment: Same as @golimar, my TV box wasn't being recognized through a direct USB cable connection with a desktop PC. Turning on `USB Debugging` in the dev. settings of the device, then connecting with ADB via local network as per this answer, did recognize it, and I was able to sideload my APKs onto the device.