# How to connect a Android tv-box to my PC?

Tags: android, adb, connect, wireless, television

I need to make an app for this device: http://minix.us/products/images/x9/NEO-X9.pdf
And I set it up, connected to my wireless, added a display, mouse, keyboard, etc. and everything works fine.
Now I am trying to connect to the device from my MAC machine.
I tried this:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.36
```

But I always get back:  `unable to connect to 192.168.1.36:5555: Connection refused`

I even tried `adb kill-server` before, but still doesn't work.
How can I connect it correctly?

Comment: Have you done [all these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421872/adb-connection-to-an-androidtv)?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I forgot to allow debugging on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADB connection to an AndroidTV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421872/adb-connection-to-an-androidtv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by allowing debugging mode. More on how this is done here:
[ADB connection to an AndroidTV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421872/adb-connection-to-an-androidtv)